# Reading unlabelled JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I am trying to pull data, using JQuery, out of an unlabelled array of unlabelled objects (each containing 4 types of data) from a JSON api feed. I want to pull data from the first or second object only. The source of my data is Vircurex crypto-currency exchange.

https://api.vircurex.com/api/trades.json?base=BTC&alt=LTC

By 'unlabelled' I mean of this format (objects without names):

[{"date":1392775971,"tid":1491604,"amount":"0.00710742","price":"40.0534"},{ .... }]

My Javascript look like this:

```
var turl = 'https://api.vircurex.com/api/trades.json?base=BTC&alt=LTC';

$.getJSON(turl, function (data) {  
   $.each(data, function(key,obj) {
       var ticker1tid = obj[1].tid;
       var ticker1amount = obj[1].amount;
       var ticker1date = obj[1].date;
       var ticker1price = obj[1].price;
    });
});
```

Somehow I am not calling in any data using this. Here is link to my sand-box in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s85ER/2/

Comment: What do you mean by "unlabelled"??? Please post the JSON you're working with (shortened to a demonstrative part if it's large)

Comment: Unlabelled meaning unnamed

Comment: Just remove `[1]` from your code. `data` is an **array** and `$.each` iterates over the array, so `obj` is a value of the array. *edit:* That is assuming you are allowed to make Ajax requests to that domain, because jsfiddle is not: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.vircurex.com/api/trades.json?base=BTC&alt=LTC. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://vircurex.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @user3353891: There are no "named" objects, so "unnamed" is still meaningless.

Comment: The fiddle could never work. See http://jsfiddle.net/s85ER/3/

Comment: Bergi, Thanks for pointing out the most critical piece of this puzzle... JSFIddle cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the second element in the array, remove the traversing and access it directly from the data:

var turl = 'https://api.vircurex.com/api/trades.json?base=BTC&alt=LTC';

```
$.getJSON(turl, function (data) {  

   var ticker1tid = data[1].tid;
   var ticker1amount = data[1].amount;
   var ticker1date = data[1].date;
   var ticker1price = data[1].price;
   // Or isn't it better to just have this object?
   var ticker = data[1];
   ticker.tid // 1491736
   ticker.amount // 0.01536367
   // etc

});
```